# Joomla 2.5 create user in php script without email address

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a a php function that works for creating a new user in Joomla 2.5.  This function is used to synchronize an external customer database with Joomla.

The new requirement is that the email address needs to be an optional field. I can't seem to get the JFactory function to work without an email address.  Is there another way to get the user created?

```
function add_joomla_user($username, $email, $name, $password, $group) {
    // Creates a new user in Joomla database with passed in information
    $return_message = '';

    $mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication("site");
    $mainframe->initialise();

    $user = JFactory::getUser(0); // it's important to set the "0" otherwise your admin user information will be loaded
    jimport('joomla.application.component.helper');     // include libraries/application/component/helper.php
    $usersParams = &JComponentHelper::getParams( 'com_users' );     // load the Params
    $userdata = array(); // place user data in an array for storing.
    $userdata['username'] = $username;
    $userdata['email'] = $email;
    $userdata['name'] = $name;
    $userdata['password'] = $password;
    $userdata['password2'] = $password;
    $defaultUserGroup = $usersParams->get('new_usertype', $group);
    $userdata['groups']=array($defaultUserGroup);   
    $userdata['block'] = 0; // set this to 0 so the user will be added immediately.

    if (!$user->bind($userdata)) { // bind the data and if it fails raise an error
        JError::raiseWarning('', JText::_( $user->getError())); // something went wrong!!
        $return_message = 'Error binding data: ' . $user->getError();
    }

    if (!$user->save()) { 
        JError::raiseWarning('', JText::_( $user->getError())); 
        $return_message = 'Error creating user: ' . $user->getError();
    } else {
        $return_message = 'Created user';
    }
    return $return_message;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla user handling definitely requires a unique email address for each user. It's tricky and I somewhat hesitate to suggest this, but what you could do if it is missing is substitute a random string or a string generated based on information in your database (like the `$userdata['email'] = $username . '@noemail';`. That way they will be easy to find later.  Of course this means password reset and other functions will never work, but that would be true anyway if the user has no email.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  This is exactly what I ended up doing to make it work.